# VS2010 Winform designer alterate decent code

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, designer, initializecomponent

I'm encountering a problem with the WinForm designer. I made a new UserControl, I added a DataGridView, some other elements and a TreeView. With the gui I named all those new components. Now it's time to code that stuff and I realise that the designer missnamed my node of my TreeView. The Designer also added new columns from my DataSource even if it was set to AutoGenerateColumn to false. I though: "Well time to clean some Designer crap again..." and I cleaned that stuff up in the InitializeComponent function (I know it's labeled "Do not modify with the code editor" but... do I have the choise?

Anyway, my problem is : When I go back on the Design view, the VS Designer seems to regenerate the code back but not even how it was. Now the designer declares my DataGridView and my TreeView as local members of InitializeComponent function. I can easily repair and undo my changes but I would like to understand and know if there is a way to disable the auto code generation of the designer.

Also, I tried to make another function which have all what I need so the designer don't screw it up and call it into the initialize component. This solution works at run time but not on Design view. I'm kinda low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the short answer is no. If something is marked as `Do not edit due to code generation.`, then do not edit it :). I would suggest reading up on [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), as that is how you can modify classes without actually messing with the auto generated code. In your case, you will need to go into the designer and fix everything there so that the auto generation works as you expect it to.

Comment: Yeah well in fact I made a partial class which does the stuff I want then calls the InitializeComponent method so the designer would be happy. But when I switch to design view it says that my kinda odd name method : InitializeComponent_so_Designer_does_not_screw_it() is not found in Windows.Forms.UserControl

Comment: Although thanks for your answer, I ll try to find a workaround and maybe make different Controls to spot what the designer have problem on...

Comment: here's a link of the full code sample

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TEVz9VyORi7vK2c4Qd7ckhmbM8cFW9j-uojSpQXXODg/edit